# Getting runtime exception when building with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am relatively new to Java/Maven and am attempting to build an existing Java app downloaded from SVN on my machine. The issue is when attempting to compile/package via Maven I get the following error...

org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource http://testserver:8080/imp-inbound-services-1.0/common.xsd can not be read

I have built this in both NetBeans and Eclipse using JDK 1.7 on a Windows 7 machine and get the error via both. I would assume it is an issue reaching the "testserver" but other developers within the organization have no issue. I see no differences in their configurations and mine. 
Am I missing some Eclipse/Maven configuration that could be causing this? Any ideas where to look or best way to troubleshoot?

Comment: Can you access that URL from a browser?

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask the developers where does testserver run and what starts it. It seems like a local process, so there may be a Maven goal that starts the server.